How to fetch data with react-query on button click only if queryKeys changed?
I have a form with 3 inputs and a button:

Slider1
Slider2
Select
Play button

I need to send a fetch request on first button click (to fetch initial data) then need to fetch data only if values in any of the inputs have changed. If values are the same then no request should be made. How can I do that?
I tried refetch but it fires everytime I click on Play button. The request should be send only if user clicked the button.
export const useFetchVoiceSample = ({ id, language, accent, expressiveness }: GetVoiceSamplePayload) => {
  return useQuery({
    queryKey: ['voiceSample', id, language, accent, expressiveness],
    enabled: false,
    queryFn: async () => {
      return getVoiceSample({ id, language, accent, expressiveness });
    },
  });
};


React Query is reactive. It reacts to changes in query key. You can easily make it re-fetch by changing the query key and make it return existing data by not changing the key (passing the same key).
function Component() {
  const [buttonClicked, setButtonClicked] = useState(false)

  useQuery({
    queryKey: [some, variables, buttonClicked]
  })

  return <button onClick={() => setButtonClicked(true)}>Click</button>
}

Now you have your component reactive to the button click, it changes state. The state value is used in query key so if you click once, it refetches because buttonClicked changes. But if you click again, there is no more change. You can use the same principle for any input value.
